# A custom javascript document.getElementById() method?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have tried out a custom getElementById() method to retrieve DOM element from a HTML page. This is the definition.

```
document.customGetElById = function(passedId){
    var nodeFound = null;
    recursive = function(nodes)
    {
        for(var i =0 ; i< nodes.length; i++)
        {
            if(nodes[i].nodeType == 1) //element nodes
            {
                //console.log(nodes[i].id);   //only element nodes have id's
                if(nodes[i].id == passedId)
                {
                    //console.log(nodes[i]);
                    nodeFound = nodes[i];
                    return;
                }
                if(nodes[i].childNodes)
                {
                    //console.log('there are child nodes inside it');
                    recursive(nodes[i].childNodes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    recursive(document.body.childNodes);
    return nodeFound;
};
```

Is this a correct way of doing it? Is this good for performance?
It has nothing to do to override the native getElementById() method. How is the native function written? Can somebody help me out? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: seperate your code and text part

Comment: What's wrong with the native one anyway?

Comment: Elements in the head has ids' as well.

Answer (score 2):

Native functions are not written in JS, so any JS approach will necessarily differ from the original `getElementById`.

Your function will also probably be less efficient than the browser's implementation, since all you are doing is reproducing it from a plethora of other native functions.

Comment: Particularly considering any implementation that gives a damn about performance will store id->element mappings in a hash table or something as it sees them, making later lookup near-constant-time.  A JS function isn't going to top that without doing the same thing.  That recursive lookup the OP's doing sure as hell won't help performance.  :P